# How to Call Custom variable from paypal IPN?

Tags: php, paypal

So i have setup my button using php to send a custom variable:

```
    $vars = array(
            'cmd' => '_s-xclick',
            'hosted_button_id' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'custom' => $lastId,
    );

    header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . http_build_query($vars));
```

What i am trying to do here is send the Last Inserted Row id via Paypal to my paypal IPN. Then use the id to modify the record depending on the payment status.

So in paypal IPN i will be looking up the table record based on $lastid.
eg:

```
$sql = "SELECT x FROM table WHERE id = a";
```

a is the custom variable that should come back from paypal.

Comment: Can you detail more your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN sends an HTTP POST of the data to your script, so you would parse it just like a basic form post.  So if you want to add the custom variable to your SQL query you would do something like this.

```
$lastId = isset($_POST['custom']) ? $_POST['custom'] : '';
$sql = "SELECT x FROM table WHERE id = '" . $lastId . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send more than one variable in custom you can use implode() and explode() to retrieve back.

**To send:**

```
$lastId = '1';
$lastDate = $insertDate;

$myCustomArr = array($lastId, $lastDate);
$myCustom = implode(',', $myCustomStrArr);
```

**To get back:**

```
if(isset($_POST['custom'])){
   $custom = $_POST['custom'];
   $customArr = explode(',', $custom);
   $lastId = $customArr[0];
   $lastDate = $customArr[1];
}
```